# Pandas and Spark on cluster

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have script that parser binary file and returns its data as pandas DataFrames. When I'm running script without cluster, it works fine:

> ```
> sc = SparkContext('local', "TDMS parser")
> ```

but when I'm trying to set master as my local cluster (that I've launched before and attached workers to it):

> ```
> sc = SparkContext('spark://roman-pc:7077', "TDMS parser")
> ```

it logs such error

```
> 15/07/03 16:36:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
> 0, 192.168.0.193): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fef3731cd70>, ('pandas',))
> 
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:138)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:97)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)    at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 
> 15/07/03 16:36:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
> 1) on executor 192.168.0.193:
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fef3731cd70>, ('pandas',)) ) [duplicate 1] 15/07/03
> 16:36:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2,
> 192.168.0.193, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1491 bytes) 15/07/03 16:36:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 192.168.0.193,
> PROCESS_LOCAL, 1412 bytes) 15/07/03 16:36:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost
> task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor 192.168.0.193:
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fef3731cd70>, ('pandas',)) ) [duplicate 2] 15/07/03
> 16:36:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4,
> 192.168.0.193, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1412 bytes) 15/07/03 16:36:21 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on
> 192.168.0.193:40099 (size: 13.7 KB, free: 265.4 MB) 15/07/03 16:36:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2,
> 192.168.0.193): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fb5c3d5cd70>, ('pandas',))
> 
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:138)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:97)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)    at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 
> 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0
> (TID 5, 192.168.0.193, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1491 bytes) 15/07/03 16:36:23
> INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor
> 192.168.0.193: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fb5c3d5cd70>, ('pandas',)) ) [duplicate 1] 15/07/03
> 16:36:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6,
> 192.168.0.193, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1412 bytes) 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on executor
> 192.168.0.193: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fef3731cd70>, ('pandas',)) ) [duplicate 3] 15/07/03
> 16:36:23 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times;
> aborting job 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling
> stage 0 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was
> cancelled 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect
> at /home/roman/dev/python/AWO-72/tdms_reader.py:461) failed in 16,581
> s 15/07/03 16:36:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at
> /home/roman/dev/python/AWO-72/tdms_reader.py:461, took 17,456362 s
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/python/AWO-72/tdms_reader.py", line 461, in <module>
>     rdd.map(lambda f: read_file(f)).collect()   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
> line 745, in collect   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 538, in __call__   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
> in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 192.168.0.193):
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 98, in main
>     command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 164, in _read_with_length
>     return self.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 421, in loads
>     return pickle.loads(obj)   File "/home/roman/dev/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 629, in subimport
>     __import__(name) ImportError: ('No module named pandas', <function subimport at 0x7fef3731cd70>, ('pandas',))
> 
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:138)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:97)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)    at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 
> Driver stacktrace:    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
>   at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

do you have any idea where trouble is?

Comment: looks like your PYTHONPATH is not set or pandas not in PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

As @Holden mentioned, I would suggest check out

1. Does python in your worker nodes have pandas? Install pandas for that python.
2. If multiple python versions are installed, make sure you are using the correct one or the one with pandas. You can specify which python you want to use in `./conf/spark-eng.sh.template` by adding:

   `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/schang/anaconda/bin/python
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/schang/anaconda/bin/ipython`
   or whichever python version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you've posted, pandas isn't installed on your worker nodes (or if it is it isn't installed for the python that the `spark-env.sh` points to). If you install python on your worker nodes you should be able to get rid of this error.